# Access Violation using SDL

Tags: c++, sdl

I have a small script which is meant to get the user's screen resolution and assign it to a variable but i get an `Access Violation` error and not sure how to fix it (I'm quite new to this language) so was hoping some one can show me how I should write it.

This is my setup:

```
//get player's screen info
const SDL_VideoInfo* myScreen = SDL_GetVideoInfo();

//SDL screen
SDL_Surface *screen;
int reso_x = myScreen->current_w; //resolution width (ERROR here)
int reso_y = myScreen->current_h; //resolution height
Uint8  video_bpp = 32;
Uint32 videoflags = SDL_SWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF | SDL_ANYFORMAT;// | SDL_FULLSCREEN;

/* Initialize the SDL library */
if ( SDL_Init(videoflags) < 0 ) {
     fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't initialize SDL: %s\n",
     SDL_GetError());
     exit(1);
     }

//setup Screen
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(reso_x, reso_y, video_bpp, videoflags|SDL_FULLSCREEN);
```

Does any one know the cause of my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't make any SDL calls before SDL_init.  My guess is GetVideoInfo is returning null because you are not in a valid state at that point.  Also the flags you are passing to init are wrong, it should be SDL_INIT_VIDEO not what kind of video you want.  Your video flags should go to the SetVideoMode function.

Comment: ah so SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) ?

Comment: @Dave http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Init  has the list of acceptable flags for SDL_Init. I typically used SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING and didn't worry about it if I wasn't using "everything".

Comment: My OCD for optimized code will never allow me to init everything if i never use it ! :P